# Whenever I double on button control in visual studio, it creates a script

Tags: asp.net

Whenever I double on button control in visual studio, it creates a script in aspx file instead of creating function in cs file.

I have checked the previous asked question but it didn't helped.

page directives are properly check

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/HomePage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Registration.aspx.cs" Inherits="MoneyTransfer.Registration" %>
```

If i try doing this with new project its working fine, only problem with the current project which I m working on. I have tried rebuilding the website.

New to asp.net & stackoverflow website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Inherits class** in page direction must be equal with **class name** in code behind.

Look up in code behind and use **class name** to **Inherits**:

```
public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }
}
```

in above code behind class name is **Registration**. then in page direction in Inherits use that.

```
 Inherits="Registration"
```

Comment: I haven't changed anything. Its all default.
`code`
namespace MoneyTransfer
{


    public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
     
    }
}`code`